# document c# class library with doxygen

Tags: c#, doxygen

I want to document my win-form app that use the class library  with 'doxygen'
I can document win-form easily, but my class library did not document  … how can I do it?
is there any way to document class library alone?
the explanation of 'doxygen' site confuse me(no picture, no example)
thanks
e.g:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// init
    /// </summary>
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //here using class library
        Class1 cl = new Class1();
        cl.Result();
    }
```

and i want my class library to be documented

```
 namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string Result()
        {
            return "test";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen did you use? What did you try so far , it is hard to guess what you tried. Did you look at e.g. the settings of `INPUT`, `RECURSIVE`, `EXTRACT_...` for a starter

Comment: tnx for your comment, my ver:1.8.5...i look it but i cant underestnd how to use it

Comment: doxygen 1.8.5 is quite old (August 23, 2013) I certainly do advise to update to the current 1.9.3 version. What did you try? `doxygen -g` and than edit the `Doxyfile` to set the right options followe dby running doxygen?

Comment: i insert summery in it and just use gui and click rundoxygen... i didn't do any thing to show classes of class library...in fact i dont know how to do it

Comment: In the expert mode you can set the mentioned settings and you can read-up on it at e.g. https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html (though this is for the current version) or you can read in the documentation provided in the html files provided with the distribution you use.

Comment: could you plz tell me where should i write it?DOT_PATH      = $(YOUR_DOT_PATH)

Comment: In Your Doxyfile, the setting of `DOT_PATH` is only necessary when the `dot` executable is not in your path.

Comment: Regarding the example you provided, you either have document also the `class` and the `namespace` or use `EXTRACT_ALL`. To see the documentation of the `private` method you have to set `EXTRACT_PRIVATE=YES`.